# How to move from Firebase Functions to Cloud Run after encountering 540s timeout limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I was reading [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/kbn31e/increase_cloud_function_timeout_540_second/) where a user mentioned that 540s is the limit of Firebase Functions and that moving to Cloud Run was recommended.

> As others have said 540s is the maximum timeout and if you want to increase it without changing much else about your code, consider moving to Cloud Run. ​- [@samtstern](https://www.reddit.com/user/samtstern/) on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/kbn31e/increase_cloud_function_timeout_540_second/gft0db2/)

After looking at the [Node.JS QuickStart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/nodejs)
and other content on YouTube and Google, I did not find a good guide explaining how to move your Firebase Function to Cloud Run.

One of the issues that were not addressed by what I read, for example: what do I replace the `firebase-functions` package with to define the function? Etc...

So, how may I move my Firebase Function over to Cloud Run to not run into the 540s max timeout limitation ?

```js
​const functions = require('firebase-functions');
​const runtimeOpts = {timeoutSeconds: 540,memory: '2GB'}
​exports.hourlyData = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).pubsub.schedule('every 1 hours')
```

Comment: If anything, they probably downvoted when they read "I did not find a good guide explaining". Guides are kind of beyond the core scope of StackOverflow instead focussing on a quick and fast Q&A style. Most of my guide-style answers all have negative rep with no explanation.

Comment: @samthecodingman That might be it

Comment: https://unloc.app/en/magazine/we-cut-our-average-api-response-time-by-30-when-changing-from-cloud-functions-to-cloud-run

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

On August 03, 2022, Firebase release Cloud Functions (2nd gen) which are Cloud Functions that execute in Cloud Run containers making this answer redundant. Links to the relevant documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling).

*The below answer is left for historic purposes. It does not align completely with the implementation details of Cloud Functions (2nd gen).*

---

**Preface:** The following steps have been generalized for a wider audience than just the OP's problem (covers HTTP Event, Scheduled and Pub/Sub Functions) and have been adapted from the documentation linked in the question: [Deploying Node.JS Images on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/nodejs).

### Step 0: Code/Architecture Review

More often than not, exceeding the 9-minute timeout of a Cloud Function is a result of a bug in your code - make sure to evaluate this before switching to Cloud Run as this will just make the problem worse. The most common of these is sequential instead of parallelized asynchronous processing (normally caused by using `await` in a `for`/`while` loop).

If your code is doing meaningful work that is taking a long time, consider sharding it out to "subfunctions" that can all work on the input data in parallel. Instead of processing data for every user in your database, you can use a single function to trigger multiple instances of a function that each that take care of different user ID ranges such as `a-l\uf8ff`, `m-z\uf8ff`, `A-L\uf8ff`, `M-Z\uf8ff` and `0-9\uf8ff`.

Lastly, Cloud Run and Cloud Functions are quite similar, they are designed to take a request, process it and then return a response. Cloud Functions have a limit of up to 9 minutes and Cloud Runs have a limit of up to 60 minutes. Once that response has been completed (because the server ended the response, the client lost connection or the client aborted the request), **the instance is severely throttled or terminated**. While you can use WebSockets and gRPC for a persistent communication between server and client when using Cloud Run, they are still subject to this limitation. See the [Cloud Run: General development tips](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general) documentation for more information.

Like other serverless solutions, your client and server need to be able to handle connecting to different instances. Your code shouldn't make use of local state (like a local store for session data). See the [Setting request timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) documentation for more information.

### Step 1: Install Google Cloud SDK

I'll refer you to the [Installing Google Cloud SDK documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) for this step.

Once installed, call `gcloud auth login` and login with the account used for the target Firebase project.

### Step 2: Get your Firebase Project settings

Open up your [project settings in the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general) and take note of your *Project ID* and your *Default GCP resource location*.

Firebase Functions and Cloud Run instances should be co-located with your GCP resources where possible. In Firebase Functions, this is achieved by [changing the region in code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region) and deploying using the CLI. For Cloud Run, you specify these parameters on the command line as flags (or use the Google Cloud Console). For the below instructions and for simplicity, I will be using `us-central1` as my *Default GCP resources location* is `nam5 (us-central)`.

If using the Firebase Realtime Database in your project, visit your [RTDB settings in the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data) and take note of your *Database URL*. This is usually of the form `https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/`.

If using Firebase Storage in your project, visit your [Cloud Storage settings in the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage/files) and take note of your *Bucket URI*. From this URI, we need to take note of the host (ignore the `gs://` part) which is usually of the form `PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`.

Here's a table that you can copy to help keep track:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Project ID: | `PROJECT_ID` |
| Database URL: | `https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com` |
| Storage Bucket: | `PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` |
| Default GCP Resource Location: |  |
| [Chosen Cloud Run Region](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/locations): |  |

### Step 3: Create Directories

In your Firebase Project directory or a directory of your choosing, create a new `cloudrun` folder.

Unlike Firebase Cloud Functions, where you can define multiple functions in a single module of code, each Cloud Run image uses its own module of code. For this reason, each Cloud Run image should be stored in its own directory.

As we are going to define a Cloud Run instance called `helloworld`, we'll create a directory called `helloworld` inside `cloudrun`.

```
mkdir cloudrun
mkdir cloudrun/helloworld
cd cloudrun/helloworld
```

### Step 4: Create `package.json`

For correct deployment of the Cloud Run image, we need to provide a `package.json` that is used to install dependencies in the deployed container.

The format of the `package.json` file resembles:

```json
{
  "name": "SERVICE_NAME",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
    "image": "gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/SERVICE_NAME --project PROJECT_ID",
    "deploy:public": "gcloud run deploy SERVICE_NAME --image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/SERVICE_NAME --allow-unauthenticated --region REGION_ID --project PROJECT_ID",
    "deploy:private": "gcloud run deploy SERVICE_NAME --image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/SERVICE_NAME --no-allow-unauthenticated --region REGION_ID --project PROJECT_ID",
    "describe": "gcloud run services describe SERVICE_NAME --region REGION_ID --project PROJECT_ID --platform managed",
    "find": "gcloud run services describe SERVICE_NAME --region REGION_ID --project PROJECT_ID --platform managed --format='value(status.url)'"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.0.0"
  },
  "author": "You",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    /* ... */
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

In the above file, `SERVICE_NAME`, `REGION_ID` and `PROJECT_ID` are to be swapped out as appropriate with the details from step 2. We also install `express` and `body-parser` to handle the incoming request.

There are also a handful of module scripts to help with deployment.

| Script Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `image` | Submits the image to Cloud Build to be added to the Container Registry for other commands. |
| `deploy:public` | Deploys the image from the above command to be used by Cloud Run (while allowing any requester to invoke it) and returns its service URL (which is partly randomized). |
| `deploy:private` | Deploys the image from the above command to be used by Cloud Run (while requiring that the requester that invokes it is an authorized user/service account) and returns its service URL (which is partly randomized). |
| `describe` | Gets the statistics & configuration of the deployed Cloud Run. |
| `find` | Extracts only the service URL from the response of `npm run describe` |

**Note:** Here, "Authorized User" refers to a Google Account associated with the project, not an ordinary Firebase User. To allow a Firebase User to invoke your Cloud Run, you must deploy it using `deploy:public` and handle token validation in your Cloud Run's code, rejecting requests appropriately.

As an example of this file filled in, you get this:

```json
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "description": "Simple hello world sample in Node with Firebase",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
    "image": "gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/com-example-cloudrun/helloworld --project com-example-cloudrun",
    "deploy:public": "gcloud run deploy helloworld --image gcr.io/com-example-cloudrun/helloworld --allow-unauthenticated --region us-central1 --project com-example-cloudrun",
    "deploy:public": "gcloud run deploy helloworld --image gcr.io/com-example-cloudrun/helloworld --no-allow-unauthenticated --region us-central1 --project com-example-cloudrun",
    "describe": "gcloud run services describe helloworld --region us-central1 --project com-example-cloudrun --platform managed",
    "find": "gcloud run services describe helloworld --region us-central1 --project com-example-cloudrun --platform managed --format='value(status.url)'"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.0.0"
  },
  "author": "You",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    /* ... */
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

### Step 5: Create your container files

To tell Cloud Build what container to use for your Cloud Run image, you must create a `Dockerfile` for your image. To prevent sending the wrong files to the server, you should also specify a `.dockerignore` file.

In this file, we use the Firebase Project settings from Step 2 to recreate the `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable. This variable is used by the Firebase Admin SDK and contains the following information as a JSON string:

```js
{
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID"
}
```

Here is `cloudrun/helloworld/Dockerfile`:

```sh
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 14 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:14-slim

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
# If you add a package-lock.json, speed your build by switching to 'npm ci'.
# RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Define default configuration for Admin SDK
# databaseURL is usually "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com", but may be different.
# TODO: Update me
ENV FIREBASE_CONFIG={"databaseURL":"https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com","storageBucket":"PROJECT_ID.appspot.com","projectId":"PROJECT_ID"}

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Here is `cloudrun/helloworld/.dockerignore`:

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

### Step 6: Create & deploy your entry point

When a new Cloud Run instance is launched, it will normally specify the port it wants your code to listen on using the [`PORT` environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port).

#### Variant: Migrating a HTTP Event Function

When you use a [HTTP Event function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) from the `firebase-functions` package, it internally handles [body-parsing on your behalf](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request). The [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) uses the [`body-parser` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for this and [defines the parsers here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/d894b490dda7c5fd4690cac884fd9e41a08b6668/src/server.ts#L47-L95).

To handle user authorization, you could use this [`validateFirebaseIdToken()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/490ea0b31400b4f925cb42e20eeae18f18742e88/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71) middleware to check the ID token given with the request.

For a HTTP-based Cloud Run, configuring CORS will be required to invoke it from a browser. This can be done by installing the [`cors` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and configuring it appropriately. In the below sample, `cors` will reflect the origin sent to it.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

app.use(cors);

// To replicate a Cloud Function's body parsing, refer to
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/d894b490dda7c5fd4690cac884fd9e41a08b6668/src/server.ts#L47-L95
// app.use(/* body parsers */);

app.enable('trust proxy'); // To respect X-Forwarded-For header. (Cloud Run is behind a load balancer proxy)
app.disable('x-powered-by'); // Disables the 'x-powered-by' header added by express (best practice)

// Start of your handlers

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = process.env.NAME || 'World';
  res.send(`Hello ${name}!`);
});

// End of your handlers

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

In the `$FIREBASE_PROJECT_DIR/cloudrun/helloworld` directory, execute the following commands to deploy your image:

```
npm run image           // builds container & stores to container repository
npm run deploy:public   // deploys container image to Cloud Run
```

#### Variant: Invoke using Cloud Scheduler

When invoking a Cloud Run using the Cloud Scheduler, you can choose which method is used to invoke it (`GET`, `POST` (the default), `PUT`, `HEAD`, `DELETE`). To replicate a Cloud Function's `data` and `context` parameters, it is best to use `POST` as these will then be passed in the body of the request. Like Firebase Functions, these requests from Cloud Scheduler may be retried so make sure to [handle idempotency appropriately](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries).

**Note:** Even though the body of a Cloud Scheduler invocation request is JSON-formatted, the request is served with `Content-Type: text/plain`, which we need to handle.

This code has been adapted from the [Functions Framework source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/d894b490dda7c5fd4690cac884fd9e41a08b6668/src/invoker.ts#L173-L236) (Google LLC, Apache 2.0)

```js
const express = require('express');
const { json } = require('body-parser');

async function handler(data, context) {
  /* your logic here */
  const name = process.env.NAME || 'World';
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

const app = express();

// Cloud Scheduler requests contain JSON using 
"Content-Type: text/plain"
app.use(json({ type: '*/*' }));

app.enable('trust proxy'); // To respect X-Forwarded-For header. (Cloud Run is behind a load balancer proxy)
app.disable('x-powered-by'); // Disables the 'x-powered-by' header added by express (best practice)

app.post('/*', (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;
  let data = event.data;
  let context = event.context;

  if (context === undefined) {
    // Support legacy events and CloudEvents in structured content mode, with
    // context properties represented as event top-level properties.
    // Context is everything but data.
    context = event;
    // Clear the property before removing field so the data object
    // is not deleted.
    context.data = undefined;
    delete context.data;
  }

  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => handler(data, context))
    .then(
      () => {
        // finished without error
        // the return value of `handler` is ignored because
        // this isn't a callable function
        res.sendStatus(204); // No content
      },
      (err) => {
        // handler threw error
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.set('X-Google-Status', 'error');
        // Send back the error's message (as calls to this endpoint
        // are authenticated project users/service accounts)
        res.send(err.message);
      }
    )
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Note:** The Functions Framework handles errors by sending back a `HTTP 200 OK` response with a `X-Google-Status: error` header. This effectively means "failed successfully". As an outsider, I'm not sure why this is done but I can assume it's so that the invoker knows to not bother retrying the function - it'll just get the same result.

In the `$FIREBASE_PROJECT_DIR/cloudrun/helloworld` directory, execute the following commands to deploy your image:

```
npm run image           // builds container & stores to container repository
npm run deploy:private  // deploys container image to Cloud Run
```

**Note:** In the following setup commands (only need to run these once), `PROJECT_ID`, `SERVICE_NAME`, `SERVICE_URL` and `IAM_ACCOUNT` will need to be substituted as appropriate.

Next we need to [create a service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create) that Cloud Scheduler can use to invoke the Cloud Run. You can call it whatever you want such as `scheduled-run-invoker`. The email of this service account will be referred to as `IAM_ACCOUNT` in the next step. This [Google Cloud Tech YouTube video](https://youtu.be/XIwbIimM49Y?t=155) (starts at the right spot, about 15s) will quickly show what you need to do. Once you've created the account, you can [create the Cloud Scheduler job](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler/jobs/new) following the next 30 or so seconds of the video or use the following command:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http scheduled-run-SERVICE_NAME /
  --schedule="every 1 hours" /
  --uri SERVICE_URL /
  --attempt-deadline 60m /
  --http-method post /
  --message-body='{"optional-custom-data":"here","if-you":"want"}' /
  --oidc-service-account-email IAM_ACCOUNT
  --project PROJECT_ID
```

Your Cloud Run should now be scheduled.

#### Variant: Invoke using Pub/Sub

To my understanding, the deploy process is the same as for a scheduled run (`deploy:private`) but I'm unsure about the specifics. However, here is the Cloud Run source for a Pub/Sub parser:

This code has been adapted from the [Functions Framework source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/d894b490dda7c5fd4690cac884fd9e41a08b6668/src/invoker.ts#L173-L236) (Google LLC, Apache 2.0)

```js
const express = require('express');
const { json } = require('body-parser');

const PUBSUB_EVENT_TYPE = 'google.pubsub.topic.publish';
const PUBSUB_MESSAGE_TYPE =
  'type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage';
const PUBSUB_SERVICE = 'pubsub.googleapis.com';

/**
 * Extract the Pub/Sub topic name from the HTTP request path.
 * @param path the URL path of the http request
 * @returns the Pub/Sub topic name if the path matches the expected format,
 * null otherwise
 */
const extractPubSubTopic = (path: string): string | null => {
  const parsedTopic = path.match(/projects\/[^/?]+\/topics\/[^/?]+/);
  if (parsedTopic) {
    return parsedTopic[0];
  }
  console.warn('Failed to extract the topic name from the URL path.');
  console.warn(
    "Configure your subscription's push endpoint to use the following path: ",
    'projects/PROJECT_NAME/topics/TOPIC_NAME'
  );
  return null;
};

async function handler(message, context) {
  /* your logic here */
  const name = message.json.name || message.json || 'World';
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

const app = express();

// Cloud Scheduler requests contain JSON using 
"Content-Type: text/plain"
app.use(json({ type: '*/*' }));

app.enable('trust proxy'); // To respect X-Forwarded-For header. (Cloud Run is behind a load balancer proxy)
app.disable('x-powered-by'); // Disables the 'x-powered-by' header added by express (best practice)

app.post('/*', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  
  if (!body) {
    res.status(400).send('no Pub/Sub message received');
    return;
  }
  
  if (typeof body !== "object" || body.message === undefined) {
    res.status(400).send('invalid Pub/Sub message format');
    return;
  }

  const context = {
    eventId: body.message.messageId,
    timestamp: body.message.publishTime || new Date().toISOString(),
    eventType: PUBSUB_EVENT_TYPE,
    resource: {
      service: PUBSUB_SERVICE,
      type: PUBSUB_MESSAGE_TYPE,
      name: extractPubSubTopic(req.path),
    },
  };

  // for storing parsed form of body.message.data
  let _jsonData = undefined;

  const data = {
    '@type': PUBSUB_MESSAGE_TYPE,
    data: body.message.data,
    attributes: body.message.attributes || {},
    get json() {
      if (_jsonData === undefined) {
        const decodedString = Buffer.from(base64encoded, 'base64')
          .toString('utf8');
        try {
          _jsonData = JSON.parse(decodedString);
        } catch (parseError) {
          // fallback to raw string
          _jsonData = decodedString;
        }
      }
      return _jsonData;
    }
  };

  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => handler(data, context))
    .then(
      () => {
        // finished without error
        // the return value of `handler` is ignored because
        // this isn't a callable function
        res.sendStatus(204); // No content
      },
      (err) => {
        // handler threw error
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.set('X-Google-Status', 'error');
        // Send back the error's message (as calls to this endpoint
        // are authenticated project users/service accounts)
        res.send(err.message);
      }
    )
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you :) Looking forward to your edit : "Edit: Annoyingly I've just noticed that your Cloud Run target is the Cloud Scheduler not a HTTP client as this answer covers. I'll come back to this when I get the next chance to tweak the process for Cloud Scheduler. The most important change would be using --no-allow-unauthenticated when deploying and tweaking express to listen for app.post('/')."

Comment: samethecodingman's answer is excellent. I would also like to add to it the following video which I found to be helpful for my specific use case in case someone else may find it useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIwbIimM49Y